# Rotate together a ImageView an TextView

Tags: java, android, rotation

I have an `ImageView` and `TextView` over it , I want to rotate them together.
I saw that I have `setRotation()` method for each view, can I use it to both views together and not use it separately on each one of them?

Comment: Try to implement setRotation() to parent layout instead of each child.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this Demo for Rotate complete view.](https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout)

Rotate whole layout which contains Image & Text.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to do Place them in Framelayout and rotate the framelayout i hopse this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this helps u.

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", 100f);
arrayListObjectAnimators.add(anim);

ObjectAnimator anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "x", 0f);
arrayListObjectAnimators.add(anim1);

ObjectAnimator[] objectAnimators = arrayListObjectAnimators.toArray(new ObjectAnimator[arrayListObjectAnimators.size()]);
AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
animSetXY.playTogether(objectAnimators);
animSetXY.duration(1000);
animSetXY.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put you two views into a FrameLayout view,then you can operate the root view to invoke `setRotation()` method .